# How to print table headers on all but the first page in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I've revised my original question because I'm new and can't reply to my own just yet... but here is my issues re-written, with more coding:

I'm using this as part of NetSuite, which is an accounting/ordering/CRM tool our company uses. We are allowed to customize our own estimates by using their form creation tool, which takes a combination of freemarker, html and xml to create our estimates.

I've designed a nice looking estimate and within this estimate I can call variables from the database. Basically shipping/billing info, items on the estimate and today I was able to add PAGE NUMBERS (Page 1 of 5 or Page 3 of 5) and place them at the bottom utilizing a FOOTER. However I wanted to also do this so that if my estimates ran multiple pages, I could print a header at the top so you'd see "Quantity, description, price" as I explained.

Now... I'm not exactly sure what the macros are for, this was how I wrote my page numbers and put them on the footer, which i'll show the code for in a bit.

I wanted to do something similar so that I could say "If we're not looking at page 1, print THIS header, but IF we're looking at Page 1, DONT print a header" so I figured i could do that page = page + 1 so it kept increasing. This idea WORKS in other parts of my estimate (for example, every item listed is on a seperate line on the estimate, and i actually print a line number, using that method, but that runs within its own routine later in the system via the LIST function)....

so any help getting this to work for my HEADER would be appreciated. I was hoping I could just do something simple such as "page = PAGENUMBER" but i can't utilize the built-in pagenumber variable for some reason, it doesnt quite work that way... here is what I have, in a simplified manor:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<pdf>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    STYLES HERE
  </style>

  <macrolist>
    <macro id="footer">
      <hr></hr>
      <table border="0" width="100%">
       <tr>
        <#setting time_zone="America/New_York">
        <td align="left">${.now}</td>
        <td align="right">Page <pagenumber/> of <totalpages/></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <hr></hr>
    </macro>
  </macrolist>

 </head>
 <body footer="footer" footer-height="12mm">

  REGULAR HTML HERE FOR OUR COMPANY

  <#if (record.item?size > 0)>

  <table class="border" width="100%" cellpadding="2">

  <#assign line = 0>
  <#list record.item as item>
  <#if item_index==0>

   <tr>
    <td width="5%" class="border4" valign="center"><b>Ln #</b></td>
    <td width="5%" class="border4" valign="center"><b>Qty</b></td>
    <td width="66%" class="border4" valign="center"><b>Description</b></td>
    <td width="12%" class="border4" valign="center" align="right"><b>Unit Price</b></td>
    <td width="12%" class="border5" valign="center" align="right"><b>Ext. Price</b></td>
   </tr>

  </table>

  <table width="100%" cellpadding="7">

  </#if>

   <tr>

    <#assign line = line + 1>
    <td width="5%" valign="top">${line}</td>
    <td width="5%" valign="top">${item.quantity}</td>
    <td width="71%" valign="top">${item.description?html}<br /><i>Manuf. Part #: ${item.item.text}</i></td>
    <td width="12%" valign="top" align="right">$${item.rate}</td>
    <td width="12%" valign="top" align="right">$${item.amount}</td>

   </#if>

   </tr>

  </#list>

  </table>

  </#if>

MORE HTML FOR OUR COMPANY HERE

 </body>
</pdf>
```

So with all that said, any thoughts as to how I can utilize that "LN #, QTY, DESCRIPTION, UNIT PRICE, EXT. PRICE" as headers on pages 2 and on? (Page 1 has our letterhead at the top and some other html coding for our company)

Answer (score 3):

As *Yvan* noted, this is not a freemaker question, but actually a [bfo](/questions/tagged/bfo) question. And as *Shaun* noted you can use the CSS id selector of #page*n* to set header/footer for a given page. The problem with this is that all the existing documentation I've seen shows that if you use the #page*n* CSS selector, then you have to define the CSS for every other page as well. So for example ...

```css
/* If */
#page1 {
  header: empty-header;
  header-height: 0px;
}
/* Then */
#page2, #page3, #page4, ... #pagen {
  header: default-header;
  header-height: 10mm;
}
```

You basically have to guess what the maximum page size will be and add a CSS selector for each and every one of page. It might be safe enough to go up to 10 or something, because honestly whose going make an 11 page order, right?

Well if this doesn't sit right with you or you just don't like hard-coded limitations like this, then I believe I have an alternative. If one defines the default header on the `<body>` tag. Then define the #page*n* CSS selector for just the page (or pages) you need (i.e. page 1 in your case,) but use the `!important` CSS property you'll get the desired results. For example this should do the trick...

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<pdf>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #page1 {
      header: empty-header !important;
      header-height: 0px !important;
    }
  </style>

  <macrolist>
    <macro id="empty-header">
       <!-- Nothing to look at here -->
    </macro>
    <macro id="default-header">
       <!-- Header HTML for all but first page -->
    </macro>
  </macrolist>
 </head>
 <body header="default-header" header-height="12mm">
   <!-- Page body HTML -->
 </body>
</pdf>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `macro` and `macrolist` are (that's not FreeMarker), but I guess you simily shouldn't initialize `count` to `0` unless it's yet undefined. That is, instead of that two `#assign`-s you could write `<#assign count = (count!0) + 1>`. Of course it matters what the life-cycle of the FreeMarker `Environment` looks like, as the value of `count` will be lost if you start a new `Environment` (like call `Template.process`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using NetSuite too and ran into a somewhat similar problem. I don't think your problem is linked to Freemarker, but to Big Faceless Organization (BFO). Freemarker prepares the xml and BFO converts it into a PDF.
More information on BFO can be found here: http://bfo.com/products/report/. That's where you have the concept of header / footer / macros.

Read section "Pagination with tables - headers and footers" from page 35 of the User Guide which describes how to reprint a standard header or footer row in the table.

The table has to be top-level to work (i.e. not within another table.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't yet know the answer to your question, but I can tell you that it *may* be found in the Big Faceless PDF Library user guide, not Freemarker...

- http://bfo.com/products/report/docs/userguide.pdf

The answer relates to the application of *special* macros:

> To display headers and footers on the page, the Report Generator introduces the concept of a “macro” - a block of XML which can be
>   repeated multiple times throughout the document.
>   There are three different types of macro attribute, which can be used either on the BODY or PBR elemnts to set a macro for every
>   page, or for a specific page by using a #pagen entry in a stylesheet.
>
> - header > to set the header of the page
> - footer > to set the footer of the page
> - background-macro > to set the background of the page
>
> A macro is defined in the HEAD of the document inside a MACROLIST. Each macro must have an ID, which is how it’s referenced later in the document. Here’s an example which sets a standard footer on each page:

```
<pdf>
 <head>
 <macrolist>
  <macro id="myfooter">
   <p align="center">
   Page <pagenumber/> of <totalpages/>
   </p>
  </macro>
 </macrolist>
</head>

<body footer="myfooter" footer-height="20mm">
Document contents here
</body>
</pdf>
```

> The “footer” attribute is the ID of the macro, and the “footer-height” attribute is the height required for the footer. If the document
>   contents require several pages, the footer will be placed on each one, unless there is a PBR element which changes the footer (or
>   removes it by setting footer="none"). The “header” attribute can be used the same way to set a header at the top of each page.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is coming late for the question, but as I was trying to figure out the same thing I learned the answer from Russ's answer and the BFO documentation. Hopefully this will help anyone else out that is looking for the same information. Using the style attribute and the #pagen id you can set a header or footer to a specific page. `nlfooter` is the name of the footer macro. I am applying this footer to the first page only. Here is the code I used to apply a footer to the first page only.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #page1 {
    footer: nlfooter;
    footer-height: 10%;
  }
</style>
```

The comment from Russ with the quote from BFO's documentation helped me realize this. Here is the quote with emphasis added.

> There are three different types of macro attribute, which can be used either on the BODY or PBR elemnts to set a macro for every page, or *for a specific page by using a #pagen entry in a stylesheet.*